# Giving the Users the option of either selecting from a dropdown menu or inputting their own and adding it to the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I apologize for the newbie question. But, I've been trying to create a special type of association and all my efforts have been failing. I would like to give users the ability to select their home cities. I've put down a few options from which they can choose, but if its not currently in the list  - I would like a User to simply be able to add it "Don't see your City, add it". Then another User who signs up later can see the new city in his list. I've listed all my relevant code below that works thus far.

Thank you so much

**HomeCity Migration**

```
class CreateHomecities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :homecities do |t|
      t.string :Hometown

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**HomeCity Reference to Users**

```
class AddHomecitiesRefToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :homecity, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  cattr_accessor :current_user
  belongs_to :homecity, optional: true
end
```

**Homecity.rb**

```
class Homecity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

**Edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :homecity %>
  <br>
  <%= f.collection_select :homecity_id, Homecity.all, :id, :Hometown %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Seeds.rb**

```
Homecity.destroy_all
bigapple = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"New York City")
techhub = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"San Francisco")
longhorns = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Austin")
angels = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Los Angeles")
windycity = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Chicago")
```

**Homecities_controller.rb** (Created new controller file based on answer)

```
class HomecitiesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
def new
 @homecity = Homecity.new
end
def create
 @homecity = Homecity.new(homecity_params)
end
private
def homecity_params
 params.require(:homecity).permit(:user_id)
end
end
```

Example similar to how Facebook does it with Education
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: wouldn't it be more DRY to use a State/City library? You could still just show the cities that are already assigned, but when they would like to add a new city, they can select it from the list. In this way you don't have to moderate submitted cities (on duplicates and misspelling).

Comment: @SebastianPlasschaert thank you so much for your comment. I didn't think about the duplicates and misspelling issue. That's super helpful. But the reason why I want to try this is so I can learn how to allow users to insert something new into database from the basic starting point that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after a few hours of searching and plugging away. I've listed down what I did below in case anyone else needs help on a similar matter.

1. The best way to solve this would be to use Selectize.js (Rubygems.org)
2. Add the gem to your Gemfile - run bundle install
3. Make sure to add ( *= require selectize, *= require selectize.default) in your application.scss and add (//= require selectize) to your application.js
4. You'll need to create a controller for Homecities, an edit.js file (customize selectize, your db, and dropdown), and a bootstrap modal in your Edit.html.erb

**Homecities_controller.rb**

```
class HomecitiesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
def create
@homecity = Homecity.new(homecity_params)
if @homecity.save
  render json: @homecity
else
  render json: {errors: @homecity.errors.full_messages}
end
end
private
def homecity_params
params.require(:homecity).permit(:Hometown)
end
end
```

**Edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
                  <%= devise_error_messages! %>       
                            <div class="field">
                            <%= f.label :homecity, "Home Town" %><br>
                            <%= f.select :homecity_id, Homecity.all.pluck(:Hometown, :id), {}, { class: "selectize" } %>

                          </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary' %>
                  </div>
            <% end %>

            <div class="modal fade homecity-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" >
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">      
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Create a New City</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <%= form_for Homecity.new do |f| %>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :Hometown %>
                        <%= f.text_field :Hometown, class: "form-control" %>
                      </div>                
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">                      
                      <span class="form-control-static pull-right">     
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </span>
                      </div>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Edit.js**

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
var selectizeCallback = null;
$(".homecity-modal").on("hide.bs.modal", function(e) {
if (selectizeCallback != null) {
  selectizeCallback();
  selecitzeCallback = null;
}

$("#new_homecity").trigger("reset");
$.rails.enableFormElements($("#new_homecity"));
});
$("#new_homecity").on("submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: $(this).attr("action"),
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(response) {
    selectizeCallback({value: response.id, text: response.Hometown});
    selectizeCallback = null;

    $(".homecity-modal").modal('toggle');
  }
});
});
$(".selectize").selectize({
create: function(input, callback) {
  selectizeCallback = callback;

  $(".homecity-modal").modal();
  $("#homecity_Hometown").val(input);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are re-inventing the wheel - that's fine if you are just doing this for learning purposes I guess, but if this is a real application you are most likely better off using a 3rd party gem.

The source data for this one can be easily kept up to date (see the readme)

https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state

If you don't want to use this, then add a button to you page "Add city", which then makes an input field available with a submit button, which then inserts the new city into your database.

Comment: thank you so much for your help as I've never done something like this before but want to try it so I can learn how to insert something new into database. Is there any way you can write down the basic code example.

Comment: You need a form with an input field, a submit button and call the controller method "create" - I advise you do some simple Rails tutorials sorry I don't have time to write code for you.

Comment: That's super cool @rmscharry - so just to make sure the controller method "create" is on the controller for homecities though correct?

Comment: Yes and 'new' method will render the 'new' form.

Comment: thank you for that pointer. I've updated my controller with new and create methods. I believe the only thing remaining is changing html view. Is there a specific thing that I need to do in the collection_select? : <%= f.collection_select :homecity_id, Homecity.all, :id, :Hometown %>